# Response from flask api giving json parse error in angular

Tags: python, json, angular, firebase, flask

Here my server which is written in flask is basically doing like getting documents from a firebase collection and sending that data(whole data) as a response. My firebase collection have like 9000 documents which I want to send as a response. Here is my flask code -

```
def getAllCredits(db):
    mainData = []

    try:

        collection = db.collection('Credits')
        docs = collection.stream()
        for index, doc in enumerate(docs):
            res = doc.to_dict()
            mainData.append({"id":doc.id,"data":res})
        print(len(mainData))
        return jsonify(mainData)
```

Although I am getting all the data as json successfully in postman but in angular I am getting json parsing error. Setting the response type to text is working but I need to get the data as json('Content-Type' also set to 'application/json'). Here is my angular code -

```
getAllCredits() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getAllCredits')
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
  }
```

I am getting error like -

```
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/getAllCredits"
SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4400/vendor.js:37062:51
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem where? Creating the same api in nodejs is working perfectly fine and I am getting all the 9000 documents in angular(JSON parsed correctly). Don't know what is the issue in flask. I am setting the content-type correctly also. Is this issue related for the large data? Can anybody help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Can you post the exact response you're getting from the server?

Comment: Error is for parsing the json data in angular httpClient - SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4400/vendor.js:37062:51.

Comment: Okay... but what is the actual response if you visit http://localhost:8080/getAllCredits (in the browser is fine)?

Comment: Yes in the browser it is fine...also fine in postman but only creating problem in angular httpClient...maybe some json serialization issue? Is there any issue in python because if do the same thing in node js like ```res.status(200).json(data)``` in the angular I am getting all the data just fine.

Comment: Let me make a guess here: your json is invalid.

Comment: If I try to get the response in postman or in a browser tab. It's invalid if try to get in the angular's httpClient(or using fetch or axios also). This json response consists of 8700 items. So instead if I sent only like 250 items in an array as json response it's working perfectly fine (both in angular and postman). But if I send all the 8700 items in json response it's giving json parse error. If I do the same thing in node 
 js then also I am getting all the 8700 items json response without any issue(both for postman and angular). Why only this issue if response coming from python flask?